# Is this a feasible LED Driver Design

Tags: boost, led-driver, constant-current

I need to control two 12V/0.16A series LED module from very dim to full brightness without flickering or non-linearity. I need 24V at 0.16A at max. That's why, I've built a current controlled driver below (10uF and lower caps are ceramic):

[image: circuit]

I've some concerns that I'd like to address:

1. I chose a bigger inductor than recommended because I use a 6W power supply and I must keep peak current lower than limits. I don't know the limit so I've leveled it to the nominal max current of power supply. Since I won't be able to see longer transients with my eyes, I guess this must not be a problem.
2. I don't care about the cost so I went for very low ripple voltage. I've chosen bigger input and output capacitors than required but I also don't want to destablize my power supply and LED driver.
3. Is my constant frequency, variable duty 555 timer setup correct? I've never seen a potentiometer used like mine. The middle pin of the pot corresponds to pin 3 of J4. R11 is to prevent instant charge or discharge of capacitor in case pot is fully turned. D2 is to separate Charge and Discharge control so that I can have full range of duty cycle.
4. I plan to separate high current and low current routes. So I plan to route two traces from J1-pin1 and J1-pin2 individually (4 main traces in total). One pair will power high current components and the other pair will power low current components. Is this how we separate Vcc and GND planes? Some people connect grounds near the IC but I think connecting them at power supply minimizes common path.
5. Is R13 necessary, I was concerned if EN pin would be left floating but since the output impedance of Op-amp is close to zero and op-amps actively pull output low, there should be no problem without R13, right?
6. Is it smart idea to add an inductor between C9 and J2 to keep constant current, how can I determine the inductance?

I'm open to any other suggestions. The datasheet is so short and easy to read, calculations are simple. Thanks.

[TPS61500 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61500.pdf?ts=1679849804226&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS61500%253Futm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dcpc%2526utm_campaign%253Dapp-null-null-prodfolderdynamic-cpc-pf-google-wwe_int%2526utm_content%253Dprodfolddynamic%2526ds_k%253DDYNAMIC%2BSEARCH%2BADS%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526gclid%253DCj0KCQjw2v-gBhC1ARIsAOQdKY22WPI_RlRXsFvLT77efVTbfrbemVakPY0B4OkO3tbtwl4KkD3SaMYaAvRnEALw_wcB%2526gclsrc%253Daw.ds)

[NE555 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf?ts=1679809337263&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FNE555)

Comment: What's the 555 doing there? The TPS61500 can do dimming on its own by varying the current set resistor (which you seem to have assembled out of a probably unnecessary number of resistors and trimmers).

Comment: Current set resistor is very small, there is no pot sized like that. There are rheostats but they are oddly expensive. I can lower the resistor count, I've just realized, that numerous resistor setup belongs to the time I didn't include any trimmers.

Comment: I'm still confused. Why did you include a 555 timer?  It seems useless.  Also, AGND and PGND should be directly connected, so it is a little strange to give them different nets.

Comment: If you're PWMing the TPS61500's EN pin then you should not have a capacitor on DIMC. From the table on page 3 of the datasheet: "Float this pin for PWM dimming".

Comment: Net tie means they are connected but only at a single point. You still need a PWM signal which you control the duty cycle of in order to use analog dimming mode. 555 timer is to create a PWM signal for analog dimming mode.